# Custom styleable attributes not working when upgraded to android studio 3.2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When i updated android studio to build:gradle:3.2.0 and buildToolsVersion:28.0.2, i  got build error (:app:mergeDebugResources) stating

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
Output:  D:\User\appName\AppFolder\Main-App\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-xhdpi-v4\values-xhdpi-v4.xml:3: warn: ignoring configuration 'xhdpi-v4' for attribute attr/centered.
```

And the related styleable attribute to this is

```
 <attr name="centered" format="boolean" />
```

I got to know the location of the problem but couldn't find a solution to deal with it.

In the previous build version(build:gradle:3.1.4 , buildToolsVersion:27.0.3), it worked fine and there was no problem like this.

I don't know whats the problem with custom styleable attribute. Can anyone find a solution for this?

Comment: Build - Clean Project

Comment: Or file-->Invalidate caches / restart the android studio

Comment: I've done it but still the problem exists.